# JavaScript MouseUp Event Being Called on Keystroke

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, mouseevent, mouseup

In my particular project, I want to keep track of all the mouse buttons and keyboard keys that are currently held down. I got everything to work quite well except I have one issue: the `mouseup` event is called on any key stroke, even if I had not let go of the mouse button.

How can I stop this from happening? Or perhaps, how can I remember that the mouse has not actually been let go, but in fact a key has been pressed that caused the `mouseup` event to trigger. If someone can find a solution in both regular Js and jQuery, that'd be great.

**EDIT:** *I just realized this only happens if one uses a touchpad instead of a separate mouse.*

(btw, I'm using Chrome)

Here is some sample code that will help demonstrate it:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'GREY';

// mouse button pressed
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(ev) {
  console.log("Mouse down!");
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Mouse down! ...pressing a key will make me go away :(";
});

// mouse button let go
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(ev) {
  console.log("Mouse up!");
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Mouse up!";
});
```

```html
<div id="text">
</div>
<div id="main">
</div>
```

Comment: your snippet is working well, I tested on firefox

Comment: I can't see where your problem is

Comment: Yea I tried it as well and it worked only with my mouse. My touchpad doesn't though. Did you guys use your touchpad for the mouse clicking?

Comment: By the way, pressing a key **should not** make the text go away; but it does when using my touchpad.

Comment: I am seeing your issue with my trackpad.